# Starting an Intelij project with Scala and Java with no POM file

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, build, scala-java-interop

I'm looking to start a project using Scala and Java, and I'm using the Intelij IDEA for the first time. I've looked up how to start a project with the two languages, although all of the answers involve using Eclipse and modifying a `pom.xml` file which I don't have in my starting project (a Java project with the Scala 2.12.2 library added).

I'm pretty new to project and build management and somewhat rusty with Scala and Java, so I'm not sure if I'm suppose to make `pom.xml` myself, if I screwed up creating the project, or if this IDE works in differently.

Here's my project directory so far, I haven't added anything to it yet:

```
project
│   project.iml    
│
+───.idea
|   │   misc.xml
|   │   modules.xml
|   |   workspace.sml 
|
+───src
```

Comment: https://developer.lightbend.com/start/?group=scala

Comment: I don't understand, I see how this would help for Scala only projects but what about having java in it?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to use Maven (indicated by the `pom.xml`) instead of Scala's own build tool `sbt` ?

Comment: Also, you might want to check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-scala-application.html - this should get you started

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse and IntelliJ are just IDEs, you need some build tool like `sbt`, `gradle` or, yes - `maven`. If you don't have a `pom.xml`, write one and import it in Eclipse or IntelliJ - they both know maven. Here's an example of a Scala/Java mixed project:  http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_java.html